# How to configure webapplication vuln scanner for local web apps

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners, automated-testing

I am in the process of evaluating a number of webapp vuln scanners. For this task, I attack intentionally vulnerable web apps. So far I tried:

Scanner > BurpPro Scanner, arachni, ZAP, wapiti, nikto, w3af

Apps    > JuiceShop, DVWA, WebGoat, bWAPP

For some reason, the scanners find almost nothing. Most of them don't even find simple sqli vulnerabilities. With Burp and ZAP, I tried automated scans and manual discovery (filling form fields which are vulnerable and passive audit active) and tried all kinds of configs. ZAP found a sqli vuln in DVWA but that's about it.

I run the apps in a virtual machine, most of them with pre-made docker images. I manually confirmed the presence of the vulnerabilities. Burp Suite Pro gives me some errors regarding SSL but nothing else. The other scanner doesn't raise any errors or other problems, they simply find nothing.

What could be the cause of this? As I said I'm running all apps locally and address them with different ports on my bridged VM, eg:

192.168.0.31:9000 > Juice Shop

192.168.0.31:9001 > DVWA

etc.

Could this be the cause? If it helps, I will post my parameters for arachni, nikto etc. but they are pretty much the recommended defaults / full scans.

Comment: I'm not familiar with all those tools, but in general scanning custom applications is not really intended to be fully automated.  "Sql injection", for instance is a class of vulnerability, not a specific one like Heartbleed.  Essentially you're never going to fully automate finding classes of vulnerabilities, so you have to treat these as tools that let you automate the easy pieces, but still require someone with in-depth knowledge of how to exploit (ZAP for instance which I have used a little). In other words, they aren't just point-and-shoot tools.

Comment: Do the tools find the site? You talk about not finding the vulnerabilities, but are they finding the correct site? All tools will report on basic information. How do the reports look?

Comment: I think some more details are necessary to figure out what is going on.  I would start with a specific, clear example.  For instance, choose one simple (and obvious) SQLi vulnerability in one of your applications and point the scanners at that particular page/parameter.  Presumably you can get the scanners to find it when you give lots of details.  When that works, give the scanners less and less data until they can no longer find it.  You'll learn lots that way.  Either way, "I told these scanners to check [unspecified] apps for [unspecified] vulnerabilities" is far too little for us to go on

Comment: A good first step might be make sure the scans are authenticated, i.e. the scanner actually logs in to the page to be able to fully spider it. I can speak primarily for Zap, but I can attest that it's fully capable of finding vulnerabilities and is automatable.